# Use of Call method on document.querySelector in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

This is the sample code I am working on:

```
var DomClass = {
    Eprcent: ".item__percentage"
};
var EPrsent = function (prcent) {
    prcent.forEach(function (cur) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("exp-" + cur.id).innerHTML;
    var S = document.querySelector.call(ele, 'DomStrings.Eprcent'); //Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation 
    S.innerText = cur.prcnt + "%";
    });
}
```

I am getting this exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` at line number 7.

How can I use document method on my HTML from JavaScript code, ID, and class which I want to use that is already present in HTML?

This is a data structure of `prcent` class:

```
 var Expense = function (id, description, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
    this.prcnt = 0;
};
```

I am aware of that we can use directly document query but these HTML are generating dynamically with unique ids. I have to put information according to element id in my HTML. ex  **document.getElementById("exp-" + cur.id)** this line use for identifying the HTML element in which i want to put value

My main concern is that how can I use call method on QuerySelector so that I can change "this" pointer to innerHTML variable? If it's not possible, then why?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could of googled "How to use queryselector"

Comment: line 6 shud be `var S = document.querySelector("#"+DomStrings.Eprcent);`

Comment: answer added about how to use `call` method on [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` acts on a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object.
Its signature is `querySelector(String selector)`

> The **Document** method **querySelector()** returns the first Element node within the document, in document order, that matches the specified selectors, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

The problem related to `document.querySelector.call` is because you are providing an invalid `this` value.
Check you are setting `document.getElementById("exp-" + cur.id).innerHTML` (**String**) as the `this` argument for `document.querySelector.call` (lines: `5)`, `6)`)

> The Element `innerHTML` property is used to get or set a string representing serialized HTML describing the element's descendants.

Therefore, using the `call` method on `querySelector` to change `this` pointer to `innerHTML` is not possible because that variable is a **String** and not a **Document** object.

---

In the following snippet you can check how we can use `querySelector.call` (nothing different to using `call` on any other function):

```js
const serializedHtml = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
console.log(typeof serializedHtml, serializedHtml); // -> string "<div id="inner">inner div</div><span>...</span>"

const inner = document.querySelector('#inner');
// equivalent call: same result using `.call` with the document object
const usingCall = document.querySelector.call(document, '#inner');
console.log(inner === usingCall, typeof inner, inner); // -> true object <div id="inner">inner div</div>

// using an empty Document
console.log(document.querySelector.call(new Document(), '#inner')); // -> null

// error code when pointing to innerHTML string
document.querySelector.call(serializedHtml, '#inner'); // -> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation...
```

```css
#example, #inner {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <div id="inner">inner div</div>
  <span>...</span>
</div>
```

Trying to bind the `document.querySelector` to another **Document** instance makes no sense to me because if you had another **Document** object, you can always invoke directly the `querySelector` function of the other document.

Check the following example:

```js
const htmlStr = '<div id="container"><div id="inner"></div></div>'
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');

// using window.document
console.log(document.querySelector('#inner')); // -> null

// pointing to the correct Document 
console.log(document.querySelector.call(doc, '#inner')); // -> <div id="inner"></div>

// but, really not neccessary because you can use the correct Document directly
console.log(doc.querySelector('#inner')); // -> <div id="inner"></div>
```

---

Hope all of this helps!

Read more info about [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

Comment: You're welcome @Mohit! Can you select/upvote this answer to mark your question as solved? Thanks

Comment: I can't , i don't have enough badges sorry!

Comment: Probably your votes are not reflected because of that. But, I think the questioner should have the option to select the proper answer for it's question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector directly on the element if its a DOM element like

```
var DomClass ={
    Eprcent: ".item__percentage"
};
var EPrsent = function (prcent) {
   prcent.forEach(function (cur) {
       var ele = document.getElementById("exp-" + cur.id);
       var S = ele.querySelector(DomClass.Eprcent);
       S.innerText = cur.prcnt + "%";
   });
}
```

Comment: But why i am not able to use call on that method